# Convert a character to its numeric value

Tags: java

If I sub out 'a' and 'b' for 2 and 8 i get 95 which is the answer i want.
But it keeps returning 73 if i give the input 28

```java
class test2a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner date = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
      System.out.println("2 digits of date");
      int edate = date.nextInt();  // Read user input

      int a =(String.valueOf(edate).charAt(0));
      int b =(String.valueOf(edate).charAt(1));

      int digita = (7+a) % 10;
      int digitb = (7+b) % 10;

      String result = "" + digita + digitb;
      System.out.println("Ecryption: " + result);  // Output user input
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to tag this with 'javascript'? Java and javascript are two different programming languages

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: "but it keeps returning 73 if I give the input 28." What do you expect it to do instead?

Comment: String.charAt(i) returns the ascii code not the number itself.  e.g. the ascii code for '0' is 48

Comment: `java !=== javascript`

Comment: the charAt gives characters '2' and  '8' which when converted to int gives you their ascii values 50 and 56 so you digita is 57%10 = 7 and digitb is 63%10 = 3 which results into your 73. Simplest change would be to make use of Integer.valueOf on the character returned.

Comment: @Vivek Good explanation; but `Integer.valueOf('2')` still gives 50.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks for pointing this out, indeed it is not the same as Integer.valueOf("2")

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help Im only 2 weeks into this field so I apologise for the lack of knowledge

Comment: FYI, `char` type is obsolete. Learn to use Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the numerical value of the character i.e.

> `Character.getNumericValue`

Unless you need integer input validation, you can reduce these two lines:

```java
int edate = date.nextInt();  // Read user input
char[] digits = new Integer(edate).toString().toCharArray();
```

To this:

```java
char[] digits = date.nextLine().toCharArray(); // Read user input
```

### Example

```java
public class EncryptDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner date = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.println("2 digits of date");

        int edate = date.nextInt();  // Read user input
        char[] digits = new Integer(edate).toString().toCharArray();

        int a = Character.getNumericValue(digits[0]);
        int b = Character.getNumericValue(digits[1]);

        int digita = (7+a) % 10;
        int digitb = (7+b) % 10;

        String result = String.format("%d%d", digita, digitb);

        System.out.println("Ecryption: " + result);  // Output user input
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the output is still 73 instead of 95 and i cant figure out why. Appreciate your help though thanks for taking the time

Comment: @GordenBobAng I ran this myself and got 95. Not sure how you’re getting 73? Make sure you are entering ONLY “28”

Comment: Oh yes its working now! thank you so so much for your help and explanation i thought my brain was about to explode